# Can template type inference take primitive operation type conversions into account?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

Templates don't seem to be able to type-infer the results of primitive operations. For example, the following fails to deduce R:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename R>
R addNumbers(A x, B y){
    return x + y;
}
main(){
    addNumbers(1.0f, 1);
}
```

even though it's clear that `float + int = float`.

Is there some way, in any version of C++, to get the inference to take this information into account without explicitly specifying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decltype` is one of the best additions in C++11.
Read more about it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

**C++11 based solution** (use compiler flag `-std=c++11`)

```
template<typename A, typename B>
auto addNumbers(A const & x, B const & y) -> decltype(x + y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

The best part of `decltype`, you can almost write any expression in it, and it will be evaluated at compile time.

In the above example, we are requesting the compiler to declare the return-type of the function, same as that of the return-type of the expression `x + y`, by just evaluating their types.

**C++14 based solution** (no need for `decltype`, use compiler flag `-std=c++14`)

```
template<typename A, typename B>
auto addNumbers(A const & x, B const & y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Usage:

```
auto ans = addNumbers(1.0f, 1); // ans is deduced to be float
```

Answer (score 5):

Template parameter deduction when calling a function cannot look into the body of the function; it simply attempts to make the function's parameter types the same as the argument types, and any template parameters that cannot be deduced this way are left undeduced. You want a form of deduction that is based on the return statements in the body of the function. This is provided by `auto` in C++14:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
auto addNumbers(A x, B y){
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Optionally, if you want to make it very specific (but IMHO not more readable), you could use `decltype(x + y)` as the return type.

Comment: Is this deduction performed at compile time?

Comment: @oink yes it is

Answer (score 1):

Function overload deduction, whether it considers templates or not, does not and cannot take return type into account. Return-type is not part of a function's signature. Deduction only considers whether the arguments of the call match parameters of the various function declarations.  The following will match any A and B. If `operator+ (A, B)` is defined, the return type will be whatever it returns. If `operator+ (A, B)` is not defined, the compiler will throw an error.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
auto addNumbers(A x, B y){
    return x + y;
}
int main(){
    addNumbers(1.0f, 1);
}
```

Comment: I fell this doesn't add anything to the answer posted 1 hour earlier